# How to rotate a 2D array of pixels about it's "center"

Tags: java, arrays, rotation

I've been given a 2D array of pixels and I am suppose to rotate this image based off of the pixel array about it's centermost point. I've tried to implement code which rotates the image based off of the rotation matrix, but I haven't been successful so far.

Current 2D Array Rotation Code:

```
        int width = originalImage.length;
        int height = originalImage[0].length;

        final double angle = 90;

        int[][] array = new int[width][height];

        double c = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
        double s = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
        int x = width / 2;
        int y = height / 2;

        for (int xx = 0; xx < width; xx++) {
            for (int yy = 0; yy < height; yy++) {
                int xp = xx - x;
                int yp = yy - y;

                int xa = (int)((float)((float)xp * c - (float)yp * s));
                int ya = (int)((float)((float)xp * s + (float)yp * c));

                xa += x;
                ya += y;

                xp += x;
                yp += y;


                if(xa < width && ya < height) array[xa][ya] = originalImage[xp][yp];
                //System.out.print("\n"+xa+" "+ya);
            }
        }
```

I've also tried this:

```
        int[][] array = new int[originalImage.length][originalImage[0].length];

        int xx = 0, yy = 0;

        for (int x = originalImage.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
            xx = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < originalImage[x].length; y++) {
                //System.out.println(array[yy][xx]);
                //System.out.println(originalImage[y][x]);
                if (y < originalImage.length && x < originalImage[x].length) {
                    array[yy][xx] = originalImage[y][x];
                    //System.out.print(array[yy][xx]);
                }

                xx++;
            }
            yy++;
        }
```

Are there any suggestion to how I can improve my code, or how this should be done?

Comment: Note that rotation always happens around coordinates 0/0, so if you want to rotate around a certain point you'll first have to translate your pixels so that the point in question becomes 0/0. There are plenty on tutorials on this on the net, did you look for any?

Comment: No, I searched for 2D array rotation specifically, but most of the solutions involve 2D arrays where both dimension were n.

Comment: Well, those solutions are normally quite easily adapted to n*m arrays. Just note that depending on the degree of rotation you might need a target array of m*n elements (or even more if you allow something other than 90 degree steps). Also note that if you only allow rotation by 90 degree steps (or even only 90 degrees) then you don't need to calculate `c` and `s` but you could rather look them up (or use fixed values) since for multiples of 90 degrees the values can only be -1, 0 or 1.

Comment: Alright, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

since you are rotating by 90 degrees you can skip a bit

```
// origin to center point
int xp = xx - x; 
int yp = yy - y;

// rotation and origin back to (0,0)
int x_rotated = -yp + y;
int y_rotated = xp + x;

//
array[x_rotated][y_rotated] = originalImage[xx][yy];
```

If you want to rotate in a different direction change

```
int x_rotated = yp + y;
int y_rotated = -xp + x;
```